# Google cloud platform, running a script from command line console

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine

I have created an app in `express` on app engine.

I would like to run a script from the command line to create the tables.
I know I can execute an HTTP method that can do that. but this is in-secured and bad practice.
Is there any official way to execute a CLI command in express app engine?

**UPDATE**

In every app you have installation script where you run a script for creating the database tables, and doing some initial things.

Or when you upload a new version you have upgrade script, this is basically what I am missing

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide more information what are you trying to achieve? Can you post some reproducible code that will give some light what you are trying to do? What kind of tables? What product you want to use? How you are trying to achieve it

Comment: @PawelCzuczwara I have updated my pose. thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to run CLI command in AppEngine Standard. You could create startup script in AppEngine Flexible, but it will run every time when AppEngine will spin-up new instance, so it is not the solution that you could use.

1. Recommended way is to use HTTPS request that can be secured with [Firebase authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start).
2. You can search for the request that you need in [API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/).